# Selecting data by year, month and week from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
Table: promotion_asset
promotion_id
asset_id
```

(a promotion can have many assets)

```
Table: promotion_tracking
id(PK)
asset_id
date_scanned
```

(logging table for every time an asset is scanned )

I want to TRY in one query to be able to identify how many times assets in a specific promotion ID, have been scanned: this year, this month, and this week.

i've tried lots of different methods but cannot find a single query that returns the correct results.

Comment: this calendar year, or rolling 12 month year?

Comment: Is Year 2011 or Nov-9-2010 to Nov-8-2011?    What is your week range (Sunday to Saturday)?   Can help, but need a bit or clarification

Answer (score 1):

I only have sql server, so I was able to test this for the Year and Month functions, looked up the `WeekOfYear` for `mysql`

```
SELECT pa.promotion_id
   , SUM(CASE
        WHEN YEAR(pt.date_scanned) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END CASE) AS ThisYear
   , SUM(CASE
        WHEN YEAR(pt.date_scanned) = YEAR(GETDATE())
           AND MONTH(pt.date_scanned) = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END CASE) AS ThisMonth
   , SUM(CASE
        WHEN WEEKOFYEAR(pt.date_scanned) = WEEKOFYEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END CASE) AS ThisWeek
FROM promotion_tracking AS pt
INNER JOIN promotion_asset AS pa ON pt.asset_id = pa.asset_id
GROUP BY pa.promotion_id
```

Comment: If you want it relative to now you can use NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll update my query if the OP says they are looking for rolling windows.  I'm currently assuming calendar week/month/year due to their use of the word 'this' in their request.

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted so it will not show up in the unanswered list for other people.